# Is there an option in "Refactor" context menu in IntelliJ IDEA to replace current empty superclass with an interface?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have an empty superclass.

```
public class SampleClass implements Serializable {

}
```

This class is extended by a lot of other classes.
I was curious: is there a possibility to make this class an interface in a way that this change will be reflected in all subclasses automatically? I tried to find an option to do that in the "Refactor" context menu, but all of them seem to do something different from what I imply to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `abstract` modifier to the superclass and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the name of the superclass and invoke `Convert class to interface`.

This quick fix is provided by the "Abstract class may be interface" inspection which is enabled by default in "No highlighting, only fix" mode. But if you have disabled it, you will need to enable it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a two step process. First extract the interface from your base class using the "Extract interface" refactoring (here I create an interface `BaseClass` and then name the original base class `MyAbstractBaseClass`:

[image]

Then you can use the "Inline Super Class" refactoring to get rid of `MyAbstractBaseClass`:

[image]

Comment: Where did you use "Inline Super Class"?

Comment: "Inline Super Class" is invoked on the class name

Comment: @MarkJeronimus I mean on what class name? Also, do I call this on a declaration of the class or on its instance?

Comment: There is only one class in this story (the former superclass which is now renamed) and 'on the class' means on the only place where it's defined, not its usages. (It can be invoked on the usages but then it of course 'inlines' only one usage)